# Обратиться к классу объекта и изменить в нем стили

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Приветствую. Есть объект `variationsFormParsed` содержащий:

```
var variationsFormParsed[1]['price_html'] = <span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000 руб.</span></span>;
```

```js
$('.product-frame').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this);
  var variations_form = $this.find('.variations_form').attr('data-product_variations');
  console.log(variations_form);
  var variationsFormParsed = JSON.parse(variations_form);
  console.log(variationsFormParsed[1]['price_html']);
}
})
```

```css
    .price {
      position: absolute;
      top: 379px;
      left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="product-frame">
  <form class="variations_form cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" data-product_id="3351" data-product_variations="..">
    <div class="single_variation">
      <span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000 руб.</span></span>
    </div>
</div>


<!--variations_form в console.log -->
[{"variation_id":3354,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":260000,"display_regular_price":260000,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"large"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","price_html":"
<span class=\ "price\"><span class=\ "amount\">260.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":"","backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"},{"variation_id":3355,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":160000,"display_regular_price":160000,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"medium"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"amount\">160.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":"","backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"},{"variation_id":3356,"variation_is_visible":true,"variation_is_active":true,"is_purchasable":true,"display_price":80000,"display_regular_price":80000,"attributes":{"attribute_pa_size":"small"},"image_src":"","image_link":"","image_title":"","image_alt":"","price_html":"<span class=\"price\"><span class=\"amount\">80.000 руб.<\/span><\/span>","availability_html":"","sku":"","weight":" kg","dimensions":"","min_qty":1,"max_qty":"","backorders_allowed":false,"is_in_stock":true,"is_downloadable":false,"is_virtual":false,"is_sold_individually":"no"}]
  
<!--variationsFormParsed[1]['price_html'] в console.log -->
var variationsFormParsed[1]['price_html'] = <span class="price"><span class="amount">260.000 руб.</span></span>
```

Нужно обратиться к блоку с классом `price`, чтобы поменять в нем стили. так у меня не получается..
`variationsFormParsed.find('.price').css("top",(height+32)+"px");`

Comment: `var variationsFormParsed = <span class="price">...`  это не допустимый синтаксис. Вы хотите объект jQuery? `var variationsFormParsed = $('<span class="price">...');`

Comment: @Peter Olson нет, я получил распарсенный json объект 
`var variationsFormParsed = JSON.parse(variations_form); console.log(variationsFormParsed[1]['price_html']);`
который в консоли показал: `<span class="price"><span class="amount">200.000 руб.</span></span>`

Comment: Пожалуйста поставтье полной пример кода во вопросе, от этого только можем гадательно отвечать.

Comment: И всё равно он не jQuery.

Comment: @Peter Olson не хотел переносить все с прошлого вопроса, но все же добавил вверху

Comment: @Qwertiy это вы о ком?

Answer (score 1):

Про "виртуальный DOM";

```
var virtualDOM= $("<div>");
var innerDOM = variationsFormParsed[1]['price_html'];
virtualDOM.html(innerDOM);
var priceDOM = virtualDOM.find(".price");
/* что-то делаем с price, через стиль */
var outerDOM = virtualDOM.html();
/* 
   вроде без параметров возвращает строку, 
   которую потом снова можно вставить 
*/
```

Попробуйте так

UPD: Исправил опечатку

Comment: на этапе `var priceDOM = virtualDOM.find(".price");` получаем ошибку `ReferenceError: virtualDOM is not defined`